# Plotting complex functions, using manipulate

Tags: plotting, manipulate

This is in continuation with [How to simplify this?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/143285/how-to-simplify-this/143293?noredirect=1#comment387178_143293). But I will try to make it self contained.

I need to do a plotting of two complex valued functions, without removing any branches or anything like that.

After I got a very nice answer for the above mentioned previous question(for one function), this is for two function:

```
$U1[k_,A_,F_]:= 1/2 E^(-I k) (2 E^(I k)
 Cos[A] Cos[F] - (1 + E^(2 I k)) Sin[A] Sin[F] - Sqrt[
  4 E^(2 I k) Cos[A]^2 Cos[F]^2 + (1 + E^(2 I k))^2 Sin[A]^2 Sin[F]^2 - 
  2 E^(2 I k) (2 + Cos[k] Sin[2 A] Sin[2 F])]);

 $U2[k_,A_,F_]:= 1/2 E^(-I k) (2 E^(I k)
 Cos[A] Cos[F] - (1 + E^(2 I k)) Sin[A] Sin[F] + Sqrt[4 E^(2 I k)
  Cos[A]^2 Cos[F]^2 + (1 + E^(2 I k))^2 Sin[A]^2 Sin[F]^2 - 
  2 E^(2 I k) (2 + Cos[k] Sin[2 A] Sin[2 F])])

 $logU1[k_,A_,F_] = -I Log[$U1[k,A,F]];

 $logU2[k_,A_,F_] = -I Log[$U2[k,A,F]];

 Manipulate[Plot[{Evaluate[#@ $logU1[k,A,F] & /@ {Re, Im, Abs, Arg}], Evaluate[#@ $logU2[k,A,F] & /@ {Re, Im, Abs, Arg}]}, {k, -Pi, Pi}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, PlotLegends -> Placed[{"Re", "Im", "Abs", "Arg"}, {0.9, 0.2}]], {{A, Pi/2}, 0, 2 Pi, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{F, Pi/2}, 0, 2 Pi, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

This is not giving the desired result. Which is two merged solutions in a single graph.

In summary: generalizing to many input functions.

Comment: You have a typo. You define twice `$logU1` and the second one should probably be `$logU2`

Comment: Thanks @yohbs, I corrected it(it was only here).

Comment: Also, consider using `Through` which is nicer than the `Evaluate[#@ ...]` construct: `Through[{Re, Im, Abs, Arg}[$logU1[k, A, F]]]`

Comment: Lastly, I don't understand what the problem is. What do you want to plot?

Comment: Thanks for your points @yohbs. I would like to plot `$logU1[k, A, F]` and `$logU2[k, A, F]`, in same plot with `A, F` slider. I hope it is clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$U1[k_, A_, F_] := 
  1/2 E^(-I k) (2 E^(I k) Cos[A] Cos[F] - (1 + E^(2 I k)) Sin[A] Sin[F] - 
     Sqrt[4 E^(2 I k) Cos[A]^2 Cos[F]^2 + (1 + E^(2 I k))^2 Sin[A]^2 Sin[
          F]^2 - 2 E^(2 I k) (2 + Cos[k] Sin[2 A] Sin[2 F])]);

$U2[k_, A_, F_] := 
 1/2 E^(-I k) (2 E^(I k) Cos[A] Cos[F] - (1 + E^(2 I k)) Sin[A] Sin[F] - 
    Sqrt[4 E^(2 I k) Cos[A]^2 Cos[F]^2 + (1 + E^(2 I k))^2 Sin[A]^2 Sin[
         F]^2 - 2 E^(2 I k) (2 + Cos[k] Sin[2 A] Sin[2 F])])

$logU1[k_, A_, F_] = -I Log[$U1[k, A, F]];

$logU2[k_, A_, F_] = -I Log[$U2[k, A, F]];
```

When having problems with a complicated problem look at its parts. Note that the `Arg` does not evaluate well with [`WorkingPrecision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WorkingPrecision.html) and requires [`arbitrary precision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ArbitraryPrecisionCalculations.html). This in turn requires that the `Manipulate` controls' output have sufficient precision to support arbitrary precision.

Sequencing of functions was changed to make it somewhat easier to tell when overlap occurs. Precision of `A` and `F` increased to support arbitrary precision.

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{
   A = SetPrecision[a, 2 prec],
   F = SetPrecision[f, 2 prec]},
  Plot[Evaluate[
    #@func[k, A, F] & /@
     {Re, Abs, Im, Arg}], {k, -Pi, Pi},
   WorkingPrecision -> prec,
   PlotStyle -> {Thick, Directive[Thick, Dashed]},
   PlotPoints -> 50,
   PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-3.5, 3.5}},
   Frame -> True,
   Axes -> False,
   PlotLegends -> Placed[
     {"Re", "Im", "Abs", "Arg"}, {0.9, 0.2}]]],
 Row[{
   Control[{{func, $logU1, "Function"}, {$logU1, $logU2}}],
   Spacer[10],
   Control[{{prec, 15, "WorkingPrecision"},
     {MachinePrecision, 10, 15, 20}}]}],
 {{a, Pi/2, "A"}, 0, 2 Pi,
  Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{f, Pi/2, "F"}, 0, 2 Pi, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

For the combined `Plot`, you need to use a single [`Evaluate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Evaluate.html) around the entire first argument to `Plot`.

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{
   A = SetPrecision[a, 40],
   F = SetPrecision[f, 40]},
  Plot[
   Evaluate[
    Flatten@Transpose[
      {#@$logU1[k, A, F], #@$logU2[k, A, F]} & /@
       {Re, Abs, Im, 
        Arg}]], {k, -Pi, Pi},
   WorkingPrecision -> 20,
   PlotStyle -> {Thick, Directive[Thick, Dashed]},
   PlotPoints -> 50,
   PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-3.5, 3.5}},
   Frame -> True,
   Axes -> False,
   PlotLegends -> {
     "Re[$logU1]", "Abs[$logU1]", "Im[$logU1]", "Arg[$logU1]",
     "Re[$logU2]", "Abs[$logU2]", "Im[$logU2]", "Arg[$logU2]"}]],
 {{a, Pi/2, "A"}, 0, 2 Pi,
  Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{f, Pi/2, "F"}, 0, 2 Pi, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

However, there is a lot of overlap amongst the functions with both  `$logU1` and `$logU1` plotted together. While the answer to your original question used `{Re, Abs, Im, Arg}`, this was to demonstrate that they could each be plotted. Normally you would pick a subset, e,g,, `{Re, Im}` or `{Abs, Arg}`, particularly with multiple functions.

Comment: Many thanks for great explanation

Comment: You already provided me beautiful answers, only if you wish this is [my new problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/145075/plot-and-an-error). Very much related to the help you provided me. Even your slightest point would be very valuable to me(as it is upto now). Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

First, it's nicer to add a tiny imaginary offset so that the argument will not jump randomly from $-\pi$ to $\pi$:

```
$logU1[k_, A_, F_] = -I Log[$U1[k, A, F]] + 10^-6 I;
$logU2[k_, A_, F_] = -I Log[$U2[k, A, F]] + 10^-6 I;
```

Second, I think this is what you're trying to do:

```
Manipulate[Plot[Evaluate@Flatten[{
     Through[{Re, Im, Abs, Arg}[$logU1[k, A, F]]],
     Through[{Re, Im, Abs, Arg}[$logU2[k, A, F]]]
     }]
  , {k, -Pi, Pi}, Frame -> True,
  PlotLegends -> {"Re U1", "Im U1", "Abs U1", "Arg U1", "Re U2", 
    "Im U2", "Abs U2", "Arg U2"}], {{A, Pi/2}, 0, 2 Pi, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{F, Pi/2}, 0, 2 Pi, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Yes this what I was looking for. This offset is need to be removed later? Is this `Through` like `Apply`. Sorry for so many ques.